# Cell contents indices must be greater than 0 error in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is a simple snippet to create an cell array and initialize it. I got the following error and it confuses me. Many thanks for your time and attention.

```
>> o={};
>> a=1:9; b=0;

>> o{end}={a}
Cell contents indices must be greater than 0

>> o{end}=a;
Cell contents indices must be greater than 0
```

Comment: o is empty, so end is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is very simple: `o` contains nothing, so the `end` enumerator will return element number 0, which isn't a valid index. What you want is either `o{end+1}=a`, or more simply, `o{1}=a`.